# error while converting yuv to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a yuv file to mp4 using:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i inputfile.yuv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.mp4
```

but i am getting following error:

```
[rawvideo @ 0000023f70bf8d20] Invalid buffer size, packet size 2649600 < expected frame_size 3110400
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame=  251 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lsize=  373766kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=306186.8kbits/s speed=0.861x
video:373763kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000738%
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] frame I:2     Avg QP: 0.00  size:1412854
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] frame P:249   Avg QP: 0.00  size:1525733
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] mb P  I16..4: 57.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 43.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 100.0% 100.0% 100.0% inter: 100.0% 100.0% 100.0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 45% 52%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] i8c dc,h,v,p:  1% 90%  9%  0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f70bfaae0] kb/s:304966.66
```

Comment: Sounds like last frame is corrupt. Does output play ok?

Comment: It happens with other files as well. Output is just a black screen.

Comment: I was using the wrong size It was 1920x1088.